# How can I map URLs for a multi-tenanted MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, redirect

I have a multi-tenanted MVC site where all the MapRoutes start as follows:

```
http://foo.com/{organisation}/{branch}/{controller}/{action}
```

Each organisation can have several branches. For example:

The Metro organisation has two branches:

```
http://foo.com/metro/north/
http://foo.com/metro/south/
```

The Gold organisation has three branches:

```
http://foo.com/gold/usa/
http://foo.com/gold/eu/
http://foo.com/gold/asia/
```

There are further Controllers and Actions below these but EVERY MapRoute / url follows this format.

My organisations don't like the generic URLs and want to personalize them. Is it possible to change from this:

```
http://foo.com/metro/north/
http://foo.com/metro/south/
```

To this (implying that {branch} = 'metro')

```
http://www.metrowebsite.com/north/
http://www.metrowebsite.com/south/
```

Using some kind of URL mapping or URL re-direction without changing the MVC website?

I'm not even sure of the correct terminology to use to search for help on this.

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could map all the DNS entries for those URLs to point to the same webserver instance and then use a URL rewriting configuration to translate that into the 'standard' path that your application expects.

I have used URL rewrite myself (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to do something similar, so I know in concept it works.  I just can't 100% say that it recieves the full url (i.e. http://www.metrowebsite.com/north/) and not just the path (i.e. /north).  You may need to verify this part.

Essentially the module would take incoming URls, i.e. http://www.metrowebsite.com/north/
and could use a regular expression to adapt it into the format http://www.metrowebsite.com/north/

Here is an example of one that I did:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="MyRewriteRul" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="Some/Sort/Of/Friendly/Url/$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="MyControllerName/MyActionName" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

This configuration goes directly into your Web.config file - see the documentation for more details on this.

Very basic example that rewrites incoming Urls matching 'Some/Sort/Of/Friendly/Url/' and rewrites it into the format my system expects, i.e. 'MyControllerName/MyActionName'.

This is something you could build upon I think.

In regards to your routes, I would recommend modifying them slightly, introducing some 'static' components to the urls so that you don't get unnecessary path match conflicts.  I also did a similar multi-tenant pathing exercise.

Consider doing the following:

```
http://foo.com/o/{organisation}/b/{branch}/{controller}/{action}
```

You can then have a match rule as such:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Organisation.Default",
            "o/{organisation}/b/{branch}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { siteView = "Public", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" });
```

Which won't conflict with your default routes, as the /o and /b parts clearly signify that its route for an organisation.  You can obviously modify this as you like, just something to consider.  :)